# LDAP browser with AD error

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am trying to connect to Active directory with a custom schema through LDAP browser.

Getting the below error.

> Communication Error
>   server 'ldap:// tat domain:port is down or unavailable.Reconnect?

Connection bind credentials are provided properly and AD services are up and running. Any other thing I am missing here?

Kindly help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1):

- Check that the hostname and port provided to the LDAP client are correct.
- Check that the communications security level is supported (SSL, StartTLS, non-secure)by the directory server and that the expected security level of connection security matches the port provided to the LDAP client.
- Use a known good tool such as `ldapsearch` (perhaps with verbose and debugging options activated) to connect to the directory server with the same parameters provided to the  LDAP client.